# Need info about WTWebUIAUTO package in .NET

Tags: page-objects

I have recently gone through a Test Automation pattern i.e., BeyondPageObjectpattern in Selenium. While going through the code I came across a package WTWebUIAuto. Can anybody give me some info about this package ? I am not able to find any info about this package any where.

Thanks,
Praveen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually wrote that library while I was at a company creating automation for them.  I had plans to open source it, but unfortunately never was able to and have since moved to a different company.  In the presentation I was using the library I created, however you can build your own abstraction layer that does many of the things I talked about as well, or use other existing libraries that provide similar functionality.

I have recently discovered and been using "Geb" which is an abstraction on top of Selenium that does almost everything that was in the WTWebUIAuto library I wrote, and even goes beyond and has some additional functionality that I really like.  It requires you to write your code in Groovy, but I would recommend this library.  Whoever created it thought nearly identically to me in terms of how they wanted a UI Automation library to function.

Comment: Thank you so much Sam... Can you pls suggest me libraries like Geb for C#?                                         Your presentation is too good, I am trying to implement that in my project.

Comment: A lot of what I did made Selenium behave more like Microsoft's Coded UI which is available for C# in some of the Visual Studio packages.  You might start there.  I'm not aware of any other similar libraries specifically for C#, which is why I wrote my own.